# writing only dictionary values into a text file

Tags: python, file-io, dictionary

I just want to write dictionary values into text file line wise line.I can write whole dictionary in to the file using:

```
log_disk={}
log=open('log.txt','w')
log.write(str(log_disk))
log.close()
```

Any help will be appreciated.In addition I want to avoid those keys which have value 'Empty' while writing into the file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just loop over the values then:

```
with open('log.txt','w') as log:
    for value in log_disk.values():
        log.write('{}\n'.format(value))
```

Comment: how to split values further which are stored as list into new lines??

Comment: @user3787457: if your values themselves are lists, then loop over each value too. `for value in log_disk.values():`, `for elem in value:`, `log.write('{}\n'.format(elem))`.

Answer (score 0):

## Write data as JSON unformatted string

You may dump the data as JSON, without formatting JSON data it is written on one line.

Do not forget to append newline:

```
>>> import json
>>> data = {}
>>> with open(fname, "a") as f:
...     json.dump(data, f)
...     f.write("\n")
...
```

Try with another data:

```
>>> data = {"a": "aha", "b": "bebe"}
>>> with open(fname, "a") as f:
...     json.dump(data, f)
...     f.write("\n")
...
```

It does not have to be dictionary, lists are working too:

```
>>> data = range(10)
>>> data
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> with open(fname, "a") as f:
...     json.dump(data, f)
...     f.write("\n")
...
```

## Reading data line by line

```
>>> with open(fname) as f:
...     for line in f:
...         print json.loads(line)
...
{}
{u'a': u'aha', u'b': u'bebe'}
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to convert log_disk.values() to a list and you can write them directly

```
with open(filename) as openfile:
    json.dump(list(log_disk.values()), file)
```